# Однородные подлежащие или синтаксически неделимые (цельное) словосочетание

Tags: синтаксис

В предложении **Что-то грустное, прощальное слышится и видится в осеннем лесу** как лучше рассматривать подлежащее: Что-то грустное, прощальное - как одно цельное или однородные подлежащие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то грустное, прощальное-подлежащее, выраженное слитным сочетанием
 " неопр.мест. +прилагательное"
https://studopedia.su/13_166588_virazhenie-podlezhashchego-slovosochetaniyami.html

Я думаю, это всё-таки одно подлежащее, а не два однородных, ведь имеется в виду какой-то один образ. Второе определение как бы уточняет первое. Что-то грустное, похожее на прощальное.

Comment: "Ну, вот и я, ― сказал кто-то высокий, невидимый".   Здесь тоже неделимое подлежащее? Его даже обособить можно при желании, да и ряд можно продлить.

Comment: При обособлении и предложение будет другое. Кто-то высокий, невидимый - размытый образ высокого и невидимого человека. Кто-то, высокий и невидимый, сказал... - упор на качества невидимого образа. Нет логики: зачем заострять внимание на качествах того, кого мы не видим? Если, конечно, не будет дальше задействована его высота.

Comment: Всё это признаки ЛЮБОГО  необособленного ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ в постпозиции, на которое в этом случае падает логическое ударение. Нельзя же все эти конструкции считать наразложимыми сочетаниями. Это совершенно разные вещи.

Comment: Почему же любого? Только относящегося к неопределённому местоимению, а другое распространённое определение не обособляется по другим причинам, например, если стоит перед определяемым словом, тогда  оборот войдёт в свободное сочетание - двучленное, трёхчленное.

Answer (score 1):

**Что-то** грустное, прощальное слышится и видится в осеннем лесу..

Подлежащее ***что-то*** и однородные определения ***грустное, прощальное***.

Слово  с неопределенным значением (неопределенное местоимение) часто имеет определение, но не всегда.

Сравнить: **Тебе привиделось что-то**. Здесь нет определения.

Comment: Что-то неприятное было во всем его облике.. Где подлежащее?

Comment: Что-то - подлежащее. Можно сказать: Что-то было во всем его облике, заставившее меня остановиться. Обособленное определение не входит в состав подлежащего.

Comment: Нет, в учебнике говорится, что подлежащее Что-то неприятное. [Русский язык / Курс русского языка. Синтаксис и пунктуация / 1.2. Подлежащее](http://licey.net/free/sskii_yazyk-/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/)

Comment: Поэтому возник вопрос.

Comment: Учебник - это еще не абсолютная истина. А Вы сами-то как думаете? Докажите свою точку зрения. Местоимение может иметь много распространителей (однородный ряд, обособленное определение), и все они входят в состав подлежащего?

Comment: Авторы профессора. Если бы не было повтора, я бы однозначно ответил: подлежащее: Что-то грустное. Поскольку здесь смысл не  в том, что возникло что-то, а в том, что возникло грустное, прощальное. Само по себе "что-то" не может быть грустным, прощальным. Поскольку местоимение указывает на неопределенность.

Comment: Вы и сами, наверное, знаете, что подлежащее может выражаться цельным словосочетанием.

Comment: Подлежащее  - это грамматическое понятие, а не семантическое.  Отец с сыном поедут отдыхать - пример из вашего учебника. Подлежащее - это предмет, к которому относится действие, а он может быть выражен различным образом. Что-то насторожило меня в нем. Что-то (странное) насторожило меня в нем.

Comment: Понятно, что грамматическое. Но разве неопределенные местоимения могут иметь при себе определения? Что-то странное - тоже подлежащее. (Что-то)Странное -насторожило меня.

Comment: Правила ПАС§ 50. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118 Не обособляются определения, стоящие после местоимений отрицательных, неопределенных, указательных, образующие с ними единую группу (ударение падает на определение): Ничто человеческое ему не чуждо; В предрассветной глубокой темени увидел, как через забор махнул кто-то большой, грузный (Шол.);Но при наличии уточняющего  значения определения обособляются:  Ни разу я не слышал, чтобы кто-нибудь, даже самый отчаявшийся, взялся при ней грубить или капризничать (Расп.).  (Здесь единая группа - это тесная связь  с определением).

Comment: Задал вопрос Грамме.ру. Посмотрим,что ответят.

Comment: Я могу предположить возможность вариативного решения. Если определение можно убрать из предложения без нарушения структуры, то это действительно определение. Если же это сделать невозможно, то не исключено, что оно входит в состав подлежащего.  Это как в сказуемом: прилагательное может являться именной частью, а может быть обособленным определением: Мы пришли утомленные. - Наконец мы заснули, утомленные.

Comment: Мне тоже так кажется.

Comment: В Правилах ПАС§ 50 ясно написано:определения, стоящие после местоимений отрицательных, неопределенных, указательных, образующие с ними единую группу (ударение падает на определение). Единая группа и есть слитное сочетание, а в сочетании уже указаны определения к местоимениям. Слитное же сочетание является одним членом предложения - здесь подлежащим.

Comment: Единую группу можно по-разному понять, например, как тесную связь, произношение без паузы, отсутствие обособления. А тесная связь - это еще не неделимое сочетание.   Тогда любое необособленное определение  в постпозиции можно считать неразложимым сочетанием, это тоже единая группа (по дороге зимней, скучной). А вот еще пример: Будто маячит перед ним кто-то высокий, черный. Здесь определение можно убрать, можно обособить.